# How do I change right click to left click when in timeline mode?

Tags: modeling, timeline

[image]

As you can see in my preference, it is set to left click so that when I click on an object I can click on it using the left button.

[image]

Unfortunately when I am in the timeline mode, when I have to click on a key frame I have to click using the right button, not the left button because I have changed this setting. Is there something I can do so I can use the left button when in timeline mode instead of using the right button?

Answer (score 2):

Found this online and it worked for me:

The Timeline scrubbing is under: File > User Preferences... > Input > Animation >Change Frame (Timeline Scrubbing).

The "Change Frame" default was set to "Action Mouse"(I still have no idea what action mouse button is).

I changed that to "Left Mouse."

However since Left Mouse in Timeline was already used for interacting with the "Time Marker" in Timeline, I had to change that input to something else(I changed it to Middle Mouse).

Comment: Could you also provide a link?

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?418763-When-my-Input-Select-with-is-quot-Left-quot-I-can-t-scrub-the-green-timeline-bar-Please-Help

Comment: I did not have the "timeline marker" issue that he had. I think my shortcut for "move timeline marker" was control g.

Answer (score 0):

Digiworkbench, thanks however when you change the move timeline scrub position or "change frame" it alters the "move markers" commands. So here is what I used to offset the "move markers". Even in the 2.8 build I thought they would change this since of the new face lift and getting to standards this is huge in every compositing, editing, 3D software left click to move everything(intuitive) and to alter LMB is ctrl, alt or shift simple and RMB used for menus and such, WTH dev team.

[image]